# Missing Files Umbraco7.2.6 installed in VS 13

Tags: visual-studio-2013, umbraco7

Hi I installed umbraco package from http://www.nuget.org/packages/UmbracoCms/7.2.6
then after successfully installed i wondered some file are missing http://screencast.com/t/t5xnwQjekud

Any idea why files are missing, or maybe there is a problem in installation?

---

And one more question is this possible to transfer my umbraco project installed in IIS7  to VS13 ?? is there would be an error?

Comment: Very first line of readme says "Don't forget to build!". Did you build?

Comment: Yes, it shows http://screencast.com/t/XR288BKtPZ

Comment: Then what files are missing? Are there error messages? Did you try running the website (F5)? After package install, Umbraco will add more files during the first run of the website.

Comment: yeah i tried that many times but there is an error http://screencast.com/t/nTw5ieG3drO

Comment: Okay, looks like your web.config file is somehow messed up. Look for duplicate System.Net.Http references for a start. Or do the nuget installation process over in a new project, I've never seen this error myself :-s

Comment: Ok thanks i will try that, what umbraco version in nuget did you use?

Comment: I've installed lots of Umbraco versions via nuget. Just take the latest stable version using "Install-Package UmbracoCms" without specifying a version :-)